# how to avoid high memory consumption of numpy where method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have a python script which does some calculation on data. data has ~50 million rows. when the execution comes to line which have numpy where method, memory is gone wild. I tried to split dataframe but it doesn't help.

code snippet:

```
##Percentage Range
data_percnt =  data.copy(deep=True)
b = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
percentage_columns = []
for i in b:
    percentage_columns.append('PCT'+str(i*100))
    data_percnt['PCT'+str(i*100)] =  np.where((data_percnt['PREDICTED']>data_percnt['TARGET']*(1+i)),'Above', np.where((data_percnt['PREDICTED']<data_percnt['TARGET']*(1-i)),'Below', 'Around'))
```

memory profile output (before splitting dataframe):
[image]

code snippet which i split the data:

```
splitted_df_list = []
for date in sorted(data_percnt.DATA_DATE.unique()):
    globals()["df_" + str(date)] = data_percnt[data_percnt['DATA_DATE'] == date]
    splitted_df_list.append(globals()["df_" + str(date)])
```

and then new loop with splitted dataframes (i would expect to decrease in memory consumption):

```
for i in range(len(splitted_df_list)):
        for j in b:
            splitted_df_list[i]['PCT'+str(j*100)] =  np.where((splitted_df_list[i]['PREDICTED']>splitted_df_list[i]['TARGET']*(1+i)),'Above', np.where((splitted_df_list[i]['PREDICTED']<splitted_df_list[i]['TARGET']*(1-i)),'Below', 'Around'))
```

memory profile output (after splitting dataframe):
[image]

but unfortunately no expected decrease in memory.

i've tried to write a custom function:

```
def flag_df(df, j):
    if (df['PREDICTED']>df['TARGET']*(1+j)):
        return 'Above'
    elif (df['PREDICTED']<df['TARGET']*(1-j)):
        return 'Below'
    else:
        return 'Around'
```

but it isn't feasible beacuse of time to complete.

any idea to reduce RAM usage?

Comment: `where` is not an iterator.  It's a python function.  Each argument is evaluated, and the resulting array/frame/series is passed in.  `where` just selects between A and B values based on the truth values of the condition. Another way to put it, you aren't passing a function to `where`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're adding 10 new columns. Each column has ~50 million of rows. So ~500 millions new string cells. Try to change the strings`Above`, `Below`, `Around` to, for example, integers (`0`, `1`, `-1`)

Comment: @AndrejKesely so, I believe by default, those will actually be `dtype=object` columns, and in this case, the strings will be cached, so the only actual cost will be the 8 byte pointer.